# KDE Plasma - changing style to be modern

Tags: kde, styles

KDE plasma looks very modern.
That is until you look at the scollbars, and drop down menus (and other things).

The 90's scollbars really clash with the modern look of the other half of the interface (eg. application launcher).

Is there any way to change the style to be homogeneous?

Here's an example (scrollbar in firefox)

[image]

Comment: An image showing what you mean would be helpful. Also, does this happen in all applications, or just some. It could just be a clash between GTK and Qt.

Comment: I was about to take a screen shot, but on my home computer everything is style properly. Hmm. I will take a screenshot next time I'm at work.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can apply themes to KDE. Assuming you're on KDE 4, i recommend you you to take a look at KDE 5 theme called Breeze, there are ports of it to old KDE 4.

Take a look at here: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/KDE+5+look?content=166438